# Tangent Line Parametrization Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm pretty new to multivariable calculus, and I have almost no idea what I'm doing.

I'm to solve the following problem:

> Find a parametrization of the tangent line to the curve
>
> > $F(t) = \left(t^2−1\right)\vec{i}+\left(t^2+1\right)\vec{j}+\left(t+1\right)\vec{k}$
>
> at the point $−\vec{i}+\vec{j}+\vec{k}$.

I know the tangent vector to a curve is its derivative:

> $F'(t) = 2t\vec{i}+2t\vec{j}+\vec{k}$

Not sure what to do from here. Honestly, I'm not even sure what I'm being asked to do. By parametrization do they mean that they want an equation for the tangent line which isn't dependent on time?

Thanks.

Comment: A *parameterization* of the tangent line means to describe a set as points that depend on a parameter.  Here the *curve* $F(t)$ depends on a parameter $t$ (which might be "time"), but it is not a line (so it is not the same thing as the *tangent line* to that curve at a point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last real step is to find the value of $t$ that we're working with: We want a $t$ so that $F(t) = -i + j + k$. To find it, we set each of the coordinates equal to the coordinates of the point that we're looking at:

$$
t^2 - 1 = -1\\
t^2 + 1 = 1\\
t+1 = 1
$$

This is true when $t=0$ and nowhere else, so we know that $t=0$. Plugging into the derivative you found, we get $(0,0,1)$ as the derivative at the point $F(0)$. The parametric equation for a line is $l(s) = p_0 + vs$, where $0$ is the starting point and $v$ is some vector parallel to the line. Take $p_0 = F(0)$ and $v = F'(0)$ and we get the equation

$$
l(s) = -i + j + k + s \cdot (0i + 0j + 1k)
$$

Or,

$$
l(s) = -i + j + (1+s) k
$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense; one question though: How do I know from the question that they're asking for that form of equation for the line?

Comment: Any form of equation that gives you the same line is a parameterization of the line - a good grader would accept any equation that gives the same line (plug in an $s^3$ or a $-s$ where $s$ is, for instance, and you get the same line). But I know from taking calc III that this is how you're expected to do the problem.

Comment: Also, this line is the "real" answer because the derivative of $l$ and the derivative of $F$ are the same at $0$, and the purpose of a derivative at a point $x$ is to give you something linear that looks like your function near $x$. That's what this line does.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are being asked to find a vector equation of the tangent line to the curve at the given point. You have found the tangent vector. At the given point, $t=0$, so the tangent vector at this point is $(0,0,1)$. Hence the equation of the tangent line at this point is 
$$r(t)=(-1,1,1)+t(0,0,1).$$

Comment: Two questions: 1) How do we know t = 0 at that point? 2) Does this mean a general vector equation for any tangent line could be: r(t) = a + tv where a is the point of intersection and v is the tangent vector?

Comment: We know $t=0$ since $F(0)=(-1,1,1)$.

Comment: The answer to 2) is yes, where $a$ is the point at which we are finding the tangent.

Comment: Ok that makes much more sense, thanks